# PHP: Trying to come up with a "prev" and "next" link

Tags: php, math, hyperlink

I'm displaying 10 records per page. The variables I have currently that I'm working with are..

```
$total = total number of records
$page  = whats the current page I'm displaying
```

I placed this at the top of my page...

```
if ( $_GET['page'] == '' ) { $page = 1; } //if no page is specified set it to `1`
else { $page = ($_GET['page']); }  // if page is specified set it
```

Here are my two links...

```
    if ( $page != 1 ) { echo '<div style="float:left" ><a href="index.php?page='. ( $page - 1 ) .'" rev="prev" >Prev</a></div>'; }     
    if ( !( ( $total / ( 10 * $page ) ) < $page ) ) { echo '<div style="float:right" ><a href="index.php?page='. ( $page + 1 ) .'" rev="next" >Next</a></div>'; }
```

Now I guess (unless I'm not thinking of something) that I can display the "Prev" link every time except when the page is '1'. How can make it where the "Next" link doesn't show on the last page though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your last line of code with:

```
if ($page*10 < $total) echo '<div style="float:right" ><a href="index.php?page='. ( $page + 1 ) .'" rev="next" >Next</a></div>';
```

Comment: works great thanks don't know why i didn't think of it :( I was going to complicated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
!( ( $total / ( 10 * $page ) ) < $page )
```

I ... don't think this is correct.

Suppose `$total` is 1000 - then on page 99, 1000/990 *is* less than 99, but there's still another page to show.

What you probably want is to check whether `10 * $page` is greater than or equal to `$total`.

Answer (score 1):

You need the total divided by the pagecount `($total / 10)` with an extra page if there is a remainder.  Use the [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function.

```
$page < ceil($total / 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is something that comes up so often in web projects, that it's usually best to create some kind of class somewhere, or at least some conveniences functions, that give you everything you need.

Here's a function that would return a dictionary of things that might be useful:

```
function pagination($numberItems, $perPage, $currentPage) {
    $numPages = ceil($numberItems/$perPage);
    return array( 
        'numberPages' => $numPages,
        'start' => ($currentPage - 1) * $perPage + 1,
        'end' => min($currentPage * $perPage, $numberItems),
        'hasNext' => $page != $numPages,
        'hasPrev' => $page != 1
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Pagination class is the best option. There is many such classes over here :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in the last line:

```
$totalPages = ceil( $total / 10 );
if ( $page < $totalPages ) ) { echo "<div style="float:right" ><a href="index.php?page='. ( $page + 1 ) .'" rev="next" >Next</a></div>"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// lets get total number of pages here
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$totalItems = 105; // just for example
$pagesNo = ceil( $totalItems / $itemsPerPage );

// get the current page here...
$current = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;    // if page is defined, use it, instead use 1
$current = ( $current > 0 ) ? $current : 1;                    // if page was -1,-2... for instance, use 1

// show us 'Prev' button
echo ( $current > 1) ? "<a href='".($current-1)."'>Prev</a>" : "";

// show current page NO
echo $current;

// show 'Next' button
echo ( $current < $pagesNo) ? "<a href='".($current+1)."'>Next</a>" : "";
```

Should be like this... This is just quick code... Later, work on some page span (set how many pages should be shown before/after current page number...)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to detect if you're on the first or the last page and "guard" the code against those conditions.

```
if (/* not the first page */) {
  // print the prev link
}

if (/* not the last page */) {
  // print the next link
}
```

You already have the code to detect if page=1 so now you just need to determine if you're on the last page or not (integer division or ceil() should be the way to go).

For pages of PHP results from SQL, there's a neat article on PHPFreaks http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination